# Three videos next to each other flexbox problem

Tags: css, flexbox, html5-video

My goal is to have three videos next to each other and my approach was to use flexbox.

The problem is that when the viewport width changes, on every +/- 3rd pixel one of the videos does not take the full width of the div it is in. I have tried several things like setting the width of the videos to 100% but it still doesn't work.

What would be a elegant way to avoid that column appearing. In the provided code it is on the right side of the middle video in green colour, just fiddle a bit with the page width and you will see it

[image: Edit fragrant-tdd-89j2g5]

Comment: This isn't the problem, but what were you hoping .video video would select?

Comment: I see the problem on Edge/Chrome but not on Firefox (all on Windows 10). Are you certain that part of the video is not shown? It looks more like a sort of rounding error that systems sometimes get when trying to work out where to place boundaries when part CSS pixels (which map to several screen pixels) are involved. Incidentally, I found it easier to spot the 'line' if the color were magenta not green.

Comment: You are right .video video makes no sense, I deleted it. The videos are always fully shown, and the problem is exactly what you stated - the rounding error. I am just thinking of ways to prevent this 'line' as it looks bad. One way is to make the background-color similar to what the edge of the video is, but this is more of a workaround. Another thing which I fail to accomplish is to resize the middle video as to take the full width no matter what. Do you have any ideas how to solve this challange?

Answer (score 0):

Just give margin:0 to body. It will be fixed automatically.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Did you try it in the sandbox?